# Is there a simple cross platform HID module for python?

Tags: python, usb, hid, pywinusb

I'm trying to write some code that will fetch receive data from usb HID devices like scales. I've used pywinusb for windows but I need it to be cross platform. pyhid says it's just for Mac OS X. The only cross-platform module I've found so far is libhid which is written in C but still python accessible. However, I haven't found any helpful internet sources on how to use it in python.

All I need to do is read the weight from usb scales.

Are there any other cross-platform python HID modules>?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [cython-hidapi](https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi)? It is a cython wrapper around the excellent [hidapi C library](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi).

The [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hidapi/0.7.0-1) report that it works on POSIX, Mac OS X, and Windows operating systems.

Comment: I don't see any good documentation or examples for how to use it. Do you?